# counter with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so if i have this code

```
from Tkinter import *

admin = Tk()
a = []
page = 1
def numup():


    page = page + 1
    page = str(page)
    print page
    a.append(page)
button = Button(admin, text='number up one', command=numup)
button.pack(side=RIGHT)
admin.mainloop()
```

but it doesent count.

please dont be rude i just finished a huge program and this be the finishing touches. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `global page` to be able to increment page from within the **numup()** function. That should fix it:

```
def numup():
    global page
    page += 1
    print page
    a.append(page)
```

Comment: However, global variables should generally be avoided. You should consider a more object-oriented approach where the counter is an attribute of a class. Then, if the function is also a member of the class you can use `self.counter += 1`

Comment: I fully agree, better to organize it as a class. My answer only points out why the counter was failing to increment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use `lambda:` if needed so you can pass arguments to your function, I edited your program with the fix, I have tested it too, good luck!:

```py
    from Tkinter import *
    
    admin = Tk()
    a = []
    page = 1
    def numup(page):
    
    
        page = page + 1
        page = str(page)
        print page
        a.append(page)
    button = Button(admin, text='number up one', command=lambda: numup(page))
    button.pack(side=RIGHT)
    admin.mainloop()
```